# How to run marqo on macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, backend

i have been using marqo library for a week now and it has been working well on my windows machine, but today i am trying to run the same program on my m1 mac but i keep getting error.

i tried reading through the documentation and i saw this:

> Marqo does not yet support the docker-in-docker backend configuration for the arm64 architecture. This means that if you have an M series Mac, you will also need to run marqo's backend, marqo-os, locally.

so i followed the instructions in the documentation, which was to run these two commands on seperate terminal

```
docker rm -f marqo-os; docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9600:9600 -e "discovery.type=single-node" marqoai/marqo-os:0.0.2-arm
```

```
docker rm -f marqo; docker run --name marqo --privileged \
    -p 8882:8882 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
    -e "OPENSEARCH_URL=https://localhost:9200" \
    marqoai/marqo:0.0.3
```

which i did but i am still getting the same error:

```
marqo.errors.BackendCommunicationError: MarqoWebError: BackendCommunicationError Error message: Error communicating with OpenSearch backend: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8882): Max retries exceeded with url: /indexes/my-first-index/search?&device=cpu (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1042deb90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Answer (score 1):

i was also having the same issue.Try uninstalling docker, restarting your machine and reinstall docker, then run the two commands again hopefully it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).